# Magento 2 Products Not Showing on Website

Tags: magento2, product, category, configurable-product, csv

So let me be as specific as possible about all the attempts. I am aware of how to successfully upload CSV into the backend. Prior to this product load I am referencing, there were 8 configurable pants on our website. I went to upload 2 more configurables to the backend. The CSV loaded successfully. I made sure that the configurables are set to catalog/search, reindexed, cached, and all else. When the category pants is clicked on within the top menu, it goes to the pants page. There is a menu item on the left hand side that shows, numerically, there are 10 types of pants to select from, but I cannot see these two new pants on the website anywhere. Their URLS work if copied from the backed into the browser, but other than that, they cannot be found.

Comment: Did you check that 2 configurable pants are in stock and have associated products?

Comment: The configurable's simple products have stock, and the simples are associated with the configurable. The configurable product does not have stock.

Comment: Stock Status set to "In stock" for both configurable and simples?

Comment: Just the Configurable products, this is the same for items that are already working.

Comment: Can someone please assist with this issue please? All logical attempts of a fix have not worked. Unless I am missing something obvious.